# Communication Raspberry Pico and 3B+

Tags: python, c, pi-pico

I recently bought a Raspberry Pico to increase the capacities of my oldest Pi3B + tenfold in terms of sensors, buttons, LEDs, GPIO, etc.

But I can not find for the moment any protocol or Bus allowing the two controllers to communicate in both directions ...

Is this possible in MicroPython? Or in C?

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/125074/is-there-a-python-library-to-allow-i2c-between-pi-master-and-pico-slave

Comment: yes it is possible in MycroPython or C or CircuitPython - you just have to write the code for both Pi and Pico - that way **you** control how the two will communicate with each other the way **you** need

Answer (score 3):

It is unrealistic to expect a "tenfold" increase.
There are many ways of communicating with the Pico (all the usual suspects in fact).

You may be interested in [Pico as a computer peripheral](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=144&t=309323).

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will manage with this !

Answer (score 1):

I developed an Instrument which combines the RPI B+ with the PICO to control many circuits and features and capture analog data and process it from the PICO. This is all done with my GUI developed using Python's Tkinter and Matplotlib. This has provided greatly increased capabilities for both. Adafruit has an excellent page on how to incorporate the PICO with your Pi. see the link below.
https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-libraries-on-any-computer-with-raspberry-pi-pico?view=all